# Displaying names inside pads in Altium

Tags: pcb, altium

By default net names and pin numbers are displayed inside pads in the pcb editor. Is it possible to have pin names visible instead of just their number?

Thanks

Comment: You've first written "pin numbers", then you've written "pin names" - was this intentional?

Comment: Yes. I mean that Altium by default shows pin numbers on pads (eg. 1,2,3) instead of their assigned names from the part in the schematics (eg. SCK, SI, SO etc). Is it possible to make it do the latter?

Comment: What version of Altium are you using?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point, but if you netlabel everything, the netlabel will take the place of the pin number when you go to routing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to do what you want, because a schematic symbol is not a PCB footprint.  As you know, the schematic has "pin numbers" and "pin names", whereas footprints just have the "pad designator" (typically "1", "2", "3", etc, but can be anything).  You assign one of several PCB footprints to a schematic symbol (e.g. a DIP, SO, DFN, etc), and your netlist is created/updated accordingly for the new footprint - the point being, the mapping from one to the other is deliberately done using "pin numbers" and "pad designators".  Altium then by default shows pad-designators and NET LABELS, the name given to the wire between 2 pins on the schematic.

I think I know what you're asking, though, and despite the fundamental design of Altium (and AFAIK most other EDA packages) not facilitating this transference of schematic-symbol "pin names" across to footprint pads, there is a half-way to get what you want:  Assign a net-label to each net that's the same as the pin-name of the schematic symbol.  Of course, the question then becomes, "use the pin-name of which of the two devices!? (in the case they're different)", which is why I called it a half-solution, although you'd still face this conundrum even if you could get pin-names to be shown on pads.

This is why deliberately assigning a net-label (e.g. "SCK", "MISO") to the wires in the schematic can be so helpful for PCB routing - you can see exactly what the connection is for, treat it appropriately, even though the pin-names on the schematic symbols aren't visible in the PCB.

Comment: I think this may be the best answer you're going to get, honestly... You can hide the Pad Number and Net Name in the View Options, but that's about it for configuring them.

Answer (score 2):

The available approaches are outlined in the [Altium forums](https://forum.live.altium.com/posts/214882). Basically it boils down to this:

- Create a script which generates the numbers/names on a mechanical layer, then print the mechanical layer on your assembly drawing. Of course, this has to be done manually
- Add pin numbers to your footprint on some mechanical layer, then print that mechanical layer on your assembly drawing

Both approaches are .. well .. limited. So, you probably don't want to go that way at all.